# Parsing SPListItem is slower than parsing DataRow

Tags: splistitem

I use a SPQuery to get a list of 100 items.  I then loop round the list and get the values of the SPListItem

e.g. string name = mySPListItem["Name"].ToString(); (VERY SLOW)

This runs a lot slower than converting the SPListItemCollection to a datatable (SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable()) and then looping over each datarow.

e.g. string name = myDataRow["Name"].ToString();  (VERY FAST)

Can anyone explain why this is?

More code as requested.

```
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in nListItemCollection.GetDataTable().Rows)
        {
            returnVar.Add(new myObj(dr)); //Fast
        }

        SPListItemCollection items = mySPList.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem dr in items)
        {
            SPListItem li = dr;
            myObj n = new myObj(li); //Slow
            returnVar.Add(n);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the loop code where you iterate through the items?  that is usually where the problem lies.

Comment: @James Love, I believe this one is on your blog http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/list-item-performance-updating-large.html

Comment: Also this from my bookmarks for you. http://blog.solanite.com/keith/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain it simply, the SP version needs to do quite a bit more to get a column value than when all columns/rows are retrieved at once and parsed as a native c# DataRow.